# foobar2000 Columns UI Column Style Script

Tags: script, foobar2000

In the foobar2000 component Columns UI, there's an option to script the display appearance of each column. I'm having a hard time finding the documentation on how to change the font/color of a specific column of the NG Playlist.

Could someone point me out a link to the doc or give me a hand with the scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

http://blog.joncairns.com/2010/10/foobar2000-6-code-syntax/ (updated URL)